# Reading simple dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access

I have a query, that I run against an access DB:

```
sql1 = " select count(*) from MonitorControlQueries" 
db = pd.read_sql_query(sql1, conn1)
```

I want to extract the count, so I thought to do it this way:

```
anws = (db['expr1000'])
```

When I print **anws** I get:

```
0    15
Name: expr1000, dtype: int64
```

What I want is the '15'.

Comment: just add the `index location`, `anws = (db['expr1000']).iloc[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the frame had one entry to it.

```
anws = (db['expr1000'])
```

to extract the value  I did this:

```
i = anws[0]
```

this provided the result from count(*)